# Kale vs Spinach in Zuppa Toscana lasting

Tags: substitutions, soup, italian-cuisine

I know that kale is the original recipe, but I've always liked spinach better. I think it has a nice sour kick to it. The problem is that spinach gets soggy much faster and quickly loses its texture. Is there any way to make the spinach stay firm longer in the soup?

Comment: Probably not--but you don't have to add it until you are ready to serve.  The leftovers can be spinachless until you are ready to portion out a bowl.

Comment: Another common mistake here is to use baby spinach. The larger thicker leaves of "adult" spinach retain their texture much better. I also appreciate the stronger vegetal flavor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's common to add the spinach to a soup like this by putting the raw spinach in a bowl and ladling the hot soup over it. This protects the spinach from overcooking and losing both flavor and color before being served. Once the spinach is actually in the soup, there isn't much that you can do to keep it from getting soggy.

Comment: I guess this does seem a bit more fancy anyways :)

Comment: Yes it does, it's a very nice presentation. Watch out for him, he is a Smartypants.